# Better to have one uber-PHP AJAX file or a file per function?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm creating a website which will require much AJAX functionality.  At the moment I'm creating multiple PHP files each containing the processing for each AJAX 'function'.  I just realised an alternative would be to create an uber-PHP file that all AJAX calls would request, passing a specific "cmd" parameter specifying what functionality to execute server-side.
Are there dis/advantages to either approach? How is it commonly done?

Comment: it depends on how much work the php file will do, separate file will help you organize your code better

Comment: And any performance-wise effects?

Comment: Performance-wise differences are negligible. I do however favor the modular approach, with still a single-entry file that calls others, much easier adhere to DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some consolidation opportunities with a big AJAX handler/dispatcher script. You can probe for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` in a central place. And if you need proper authorization for some functions, do it for all requests alike.

And obviously you can also unify the output format/handling. Instead of replicating the header response, you need to write that only once.

But don't bother with assessing the performance theory behind this or that approach. Unless you need a very simple callback feature (e.g. dictionary checks) which might benefit from a separate script, handle it with one big ajax script. Most often a central script would provide the security and maintenance advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I use one monster file when developing and testing - then split it up in smaller chunks for deployment.
Of course there's a performance penalty if the server has process 1200 lines just to get to the 20 it actually needs for a given task.

The same goes for importing lots of unnecessary "tools" from separate files.

Do the household-tasks once, before deployment
- instead of 10.000.000 times a day - it's just common sense

It helps to leave "markers" in your source code, to enable a script to do the splitting up, and pre-including of tools/tables automatically..
- some smart asses call it unnecessary (and dangerous!) optimization - they're just lazy : )

Answer (score 1):

I personally do a bit of both.

I have a main script that includes separate scripts with `require_once();` based on which one is needed. (using a `switch` and a "type" get/post variable).

This way I can handle certain things in a central location, like header handling.

And I can also easily separate scripts without the need to read a 2k line file each time.